# \gls inside caption without protect

Tags: captions, glossaries

Is it possible to use `\gls` (from the `glossaries` package) inside a caption without `\protect`ing it every single time?  The `glossaries` package says the `\gls` command is not fragile... but I get errors unless I protect it.

Kind of annoying since half the advantage of a `glossary`/`acronym` package is reducing the amount of typing you have to repeat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Name}{name={Name},description={Description}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Blah blah \protect\gls{name}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you remove the protect it will complain about an extra }.

Comment: Robustify appears to have worked.  Thanks!  Why would it compile without that for you but not me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`glossaries` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) loads the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) by default. And, `etoolbox` provides `\robustify{<command>}` that redeclares `<command>` as a robust (non-fragile) command. Therefore, add

```
\robustify{\gls}% Make \gls not fragile
```

after loading `glossaries`.

Comment: I had to manually usepackage etoolbox for this to work.

Comment: What version of `glossaries` do you have? Mine is `2011/04/12 v3.01`. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{...}` and view your `.log` file. Earlier versions may not have needed/loaded `etoolbox`.

Comment: @Werner Also, the documentation says 'As from v3.01 `\gls` is no longer fragile and doesn’t need protecting', so this may just be a version issue.

Comment: I have v2.05 so this must be the problem.  But I specifically downloaded the latest version and placed it in my tex directory.  How can I stop the old version that comes with my dist overriding this?

Comment: @Jack: It's best to update packages via your package manager. If not, you need to overwrite the older package style file with the new one since TeX will retrieve the file (with the same name) in the same location. Updating your FNDB (FileName DataBase) may also solve this issue, as long as you don't have duplicates stored in different places.